# Change SAS plot line color and format

Tags: plot, graphics, sas

I tried to change the line color and some formats of the plots generated by the SAS mixed effects models. Specifically, I want to make the line more colorful and thicker and change x-axis and y-axis range and labels. The codes I tried are not working and there are some missing pieces that I need to put in. Sincerely appreciate your thoughts. Thanks.

[image]

```
proc mixed data=Mixed1 method=ml;
class ID Bright;
model PI_PDI = TMP|BRIGHT POC other_op_inlife_t0 / s outpm=Predicted;
repeated / type=ar(1) sub=ID r;
store out=Predictedplot;/* create item store */
run;

ods trace on;
ods output SliceFitPlot= Predictedplot;
proc plm source=Predictedplot;          /* use item store to create fit plots */
effectplot fit(x=TMP plotby=Bright); /* panel */
effectplot slicefit(x=TMP sliceby=Bright);/* overlay */
quit;
ods trace off;

ODS GRAPHICS / RESET  HEIGHT = 4.9in WIDTH = 6.83in;
proc sgplot data= Predictedplot noautolegend;
xaxis values = (1 to 2 by 1) label='Timepoints of Assessment' LABELATTRS=(size=14 weight=bold) VALUEATTRS=(size=12 weight=bold); 
yaxis grid values = (4 to 5 by .25) label='PI/PDI Scores' LABELATTRS=(size=14 weight=bold)
VALUEATTRS=(size=12 weight=bold) GRIDATTRS=(color=GrayCA thickness=.1mm);
run;
```